# Find USB port based on device PID & VID in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I want to develop a prototype for USB port communication in Ubuntu based on device PID & VID.

- Open port
- Close Port
- Write/Read operation

I am not able to find any sample app which opens USB port based on PID & VID.

All the sample code is available, like below

```
int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
```

where "/dev/ttyUSB0" is the USB file name (As mentioned in various tutorial).

But I want to open this only if the PID & VID matches my specific PID & VID.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using QT lib for that. You can use QTSerialPortInfo to get neccesary info with `QSerialPortInfo::productIdentifier()` and with `QSerialPortInfo::vendorIdentifier()`. Anyway, it's really helpful lib, and you can check all of avaliable methods on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html.

Comment: Dear Branisha, Thank you for your reply But my problem is that I am developing this for an embedded Linux board and QT is not installed there.

Comment: Since you're using embedded, I don't know what packages/headers are available to you for use. My second guess is to pass all '/dev/ttyUSBX' devices to 'lsusb -D' and see if any of those match your criteria, i.e. PID and VID.